# MySql stored procedure not work due to error which inside cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Followed procedure not work due to error at open cr_count line. When i run code without this line it works finely. Also i tried to write query without cursor such as select into even so, procedure not worked. i did not write mysql error print as oracle sqlerrm, i think mysql has not that function.

```sql
delimiter $$

create procedure proc_payment(
  in p_transaction_guid varchar(200),
  in p_card_type_id int,
  in p_card_number varchar(100),
  in p_billing_address varchar(500),
  in p_flight_id int,
  in p_flight_date date,
  in p_cabin_class_id int,
  in p_identity_number varchar(200)
)
begin
  declare v_count          int; 
  declare v_payment_id     int;
  declare v_passenger_id   int;
  declare v_booking_ref_id int;

  declare cr_count cursor for
    select count(1)
    from tbl_passenger
    where identity_number = p_identity_number;

  declare cr_passenger cursor for
    select passenger_id
    from tbl_passenger
    where identity_number = p_identity_number;

  open cr_count;
  fetch cr_count into v_count;
  close cr_count;

  if v_count = 0 then
    insert into tbl_passenger (
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender,
      birthdate,
      identity_number
    )
    select
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender_id,
      birthdate,
      identity_number 
    from
      v_booking_transaction 
    where 
      transaction_guid = p_transaction_guid
      and identity_number = p_identity_number;

    select last_insert_id() into v_passenger_id;
  else
    open cr_passenger;
    fetch cr_passenger into v_passenger_id;
    close cr_passenger;
  end if;

  insert into tbl_payment (
    card_type_id,
    card_number,
    payment_date,
    billing_address
  ) values (
    p_card_type_id,
    p_card_number,
    current_date(),
    p_billing_address
  );

  select last_insert_id() into v_payment_id;

  insert into tbl_flight_booking (
    flight_id,
    flight_date,
    cabin_class_id,
    payment_id
  ) values (
    p_flight_id,
    p_flight_date,
    p_cabin_class_id,
    v_payment_id
  );

  select last_insert_id() v_booking_ref_id;

  insert into tbl_flight_passenger (
    flight_id,
    booking_reference_id,
    passenger_id
  ) values (
    p_flight_id,
    v_booking_ref_id,
    v_passenger_id
  );
end$$
```

Comment: So fetching without the open does not cause an error?

Comment: if cursor is close or when i remove open, fetch and close lines the procedure works finely. procedure does not work due to error in select query inside cursor (cr_count), but what is that error, unfortunately i did'nt find any detail.

Comment: if we look from the viewpoint of error tracing, mysql is bad for my opinion

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can use local variables/parameters in cursors in MySQL. If you added `SET @p_identity_number := p_identity_number;` somewhere before the `open`, and changed the cursor queries to use the `@p_identity_number` session variable instead, I think it could work. `cr_passenger` must never get opened, or has a field named `p_identity_number` otherwise it would cause problems as well.

Comment: Pls provide the exact mysql error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I 'm going to try your solution offer. What i don't understand is that, i have wrote a procedure previously and it was working properly but this wasn't. As though MySQL sometimes behaves arbitrarily. Maybe i'm failing to notice a detail.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cursors can be avoided in this case. The following should work:

```sql
delimiter $$

create procedure proc_payment(
  in p_transaction_guid varchar(200),
  in p_card_type_id int,
  in p_card_number varchar(100),
  in p_billing_address varchar(500),
  in p_flight_id int,
  in p_flight_date date,
  in p_cabin_class_id int,
  in p_identity_number varchar(200)
)
begin
  declare v_passenger_id,
          v_payment_id,
          v_booking_ref_id int;

  select
    passenger_id into v_passenger_id
  from
    tbl_passenger
  where
    identity_number = p_identity_number;

  if v_passenger_id is null then
    insert into tbl_passenger (
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender,
      birthdate,
      identity_number
    )
    select
      firstname,
      lastname,
      gender_id,
      birthdate,
      identity_number
    from
      v_booking_transaction
    where
      transaction_guid = p_transaction_guid
      and identity_number = p_identity_number;
    set v_passenger_id := last_insert_id();
  end if;

  insert into tbl_payment (
    card_type_id,
    card_number,
    payment_date,
    billing_address
  ) values (
    p_card_type_id,
    p_card_number,
    current_date(),
    p_billing_address
  );
  set v_payment_id := last_insert_id();

  insert into tbl_flight_booking (
    flight_id,
    flight_date,
    cabin_class_id,
    payment_id
  ) values (
    p_flight_id,
    p_flight_date,
    p_cabin_class_id,
    v_payment_id
  );
  set v_booking_ref_id := last_insert_id();

  insert into tbl_flight_passenger (
    flight_id,
    booking_reference_id,
    passenger_id
  ) values (
    p_flight_id,
    v_booking_ref_id,
    v_passenger_id
  );
end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito, i tried your solution but unfortunately. i added an out parameter and i set p_identity_number out parameter didn't work. Whenever i removed all content except set p_out:= p_identity_number it worked finely. Fascinating..